# How to deploy a docker container to an Ubuntu server instance from Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerhub

I added a Docker task in the build pipeline to build and push the image I created to Docker Hub.

Then, I added two more tasks (copy files and publish build artifacts) so that the files are available to the release pipelines.

Now, I want to know how to run this image (`docker run`), so that the container gets deployed to my Ubuntu server instance (`209.97.179.151`).

What tasks should I add in the release pipeline to deploy the image to the server `209.97.179.151`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ssh task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops) to ssh to the remote server (209.97.179.151).

Use `docker stop`, `docker pull`, and `docker run` to update your image.

You can set and use the `$(tag)` variable to set the tag of the image.

```
variables:
  tag: latest
```